# Is there a way to trim art boards in illustrator like in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, transparency, artboard

I will find myself often resizing art boards in illustrator when Im designing websites (if a page needs to be longer or shorter) and wanted to know if there is a way to trim away transparent pixels on an art board just like in photoshop. Right now I just use the art board tool to resize it manually but if theres a quicker way Im all ears. It would be quite a nifty tip to know

Comment: There are in general no pixels in illustrator. But yes you can fit to the bounding box.

Answer (score 4):

In general, `Object > Artboards > Fit to Artwork` may help.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the `Artboard Tool` and double click on the object you wish the artboard to be around.